# How to use function parameter on @Url.Action Parameter

Tags: javascript, json, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-views

Url.Action parameter name as a function parameter. Here i use actionNameParameter as a function parameter now how i write this parameter on url: '@Url.Action(actionNameParameter)'
I tried this code but it does not work. But i write like  url:'@Url.Action("StringactionName")'  then it works. But i need to use the function parameter as @Url.Action(actionNameParameter)

```
function example(actionNameParameter) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action(actionNameParameter)'
        });
    }
```

Comment: `@Url.Action()` is razor (server side) code - it is executed on the server before the html is sent to the browser. You `actionNameParameter` is a javascript (client side) variable and does not even exist on the server - its not in scope

Answer (score 0):

```js
hi can use escape sequence for single code 

 var actionNameParameter = "\'" + "@Url.Action(actionNameParameter)" + "\'";
```